# Google Analytics: Warning: Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-analytics, react-router

I am trying to add Google Analytics to React using the guide [found here](https://github.com/react-ga/react-ga/wiki/React-Router-v4-withTracker).

I have

```
import React, { useEffect } from "react";
import ReactGA from "react-ga";

ReactGA.initialize("UA-0000000-0");

export default (WrappedComponent, options = {}) => {
  const trackPage = page => {
    ReactGA.set({
      page,
      ...options
    });
    ReactGA.pageview(page);
  };

  const HOC = props => {
    useEffect(() => trackPage(props.location.pathname), [
      props.location.pathname
    ]);

    return <WrappedComponent {...props} />;
  };

  return HOC;
};
```

Then, I call it like this:

```
<BrowserRouter className={classes.root}>
        <Switch>
          <Route path="/login" component={withTracker(Login)} />
          <Route path="/signup" component={withTracker(SignUp)} />
</Switch>
      </BrowserRouter>
```

The full error:

```
react_devtools_backend.js:2273 Warning: Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component. This is a no-op, but it indicates a memory leak in your application. To fix, cancel all subscriptions and asynchronous tasks in a useEffect cleanup function.
    in SignIn (at GoogleAnalytics.js:64)
    in HOC (created by Context.Consumer)
```

I have tried with the `react hooks` method they show as well as the other suggested way on that page but still get the same error. I am new to React so struggling to find the issue.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Trying to set the state in ReactGA.set while component is unmounted can give that warning. You can set a variable 'Mounted' to true in useEffect and in the return function set it to false which is executed when component unmounts.

```
const HOC = props => {
  useEffect(() => {
    let isMounted = true
    isMounted &&        
    trackPage(props.location.pathname)
    return () => isMounted = false
 }, [props.location.pathname]);
```

If you still get the warning move the ReactGA.set  inside useEffect and use Mounted && ReactGA.set.....